# Visual Basic - Website Form Calculation

Tags: visual-studio

I am studying my first year in Programming and I have a slight problem in relation to Visual Basic coding. I know this sounds slightly vague, however I just wish to find out whether i need to create a variable, array or function.

I am creating a website app which processes a mobile phone order. I have designed a form which includes the quantity of mobile phones a particular customer requires, and the type of mobile phone the customer wishes to order.

I have included quantity values from 1-5 and 5 different types of mobile phones. I also have a button 'Process Order'. I just want to know how i can assign a particular type of mobile to the quantity.

In other words a calculation function where if I click process order, a price will be displayed showing exactly how much it costs for the phone + quantity needed. I have included a combo box with the list of phone types and the prices of each phone.

I want to be able to create a code which links a phone to a quantity for example Qty: 2 Type: superphone (costing £45). Once i process the order I should see a total price of £90. I am not expecting anyone to do it for me, just a simple explanation of what i need to look at in order to figure out the coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are searching for the [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class.

A dictionary matches some input (called key) to an output (called value). In principle, the same can be achieved through a function but a dictionary is more concise, can be changed at runtime, and may also be more efficient.

Conceptually, an array is just a specific type of dictionary that maps the input values 0 – n (its indices) to the indexed values.

Example:

```
Dim phonePrices As New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)()

phonePrices.Add("Nookia", 12.30)
phonePrices.Add("Motolola", 12.12)
phonePrices.Add("THC", 42.00)
```

These prices can then be looked up by using the indexer:

```
Dim priceOfMyNookia = phonePrices("Nookia")
```